# Adding a field to a custom SOLR index configuration

Tags: configuration, solr

I am moving indexes from Lucene to Solr. Almost everything is working again, except a few custom indexes that have their own index configuration and had some field added to the fieldMap. Other custom indexes are working. The error I get when starting the site is:

> [KeyNotFoundException: The given key was not present in the
>   dictionary.]    System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.get_Item(TKey
>   key) +13763335
>   Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrFieldMap.AddFieldByFieldName(XmlNode
>   configNode) +618
>
> [TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of
>   an invocation.]    X.X.Web.Global.Application_Error(Object
>   sender, EventArgs e) in
>   ...\Global.asax.cs:76
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.RaiseOnError() +211
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): Exception has been thrown by the target
>   of an invocation.]
>   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.EnsureAppStartCalledForIntegratedMode(HttpContext
>   context, HttpApplication app) +544
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr
>   appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +186
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state,
>   MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +172
>   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr
>   appContext, HttpContext context) +402
>   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr
>   appContext) +343
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): Exception has been thrown by the target
>   of an invocation.]
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +579
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context)
>   +112    System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest
>   wr, HttpContext context) +716

The index config now:

```xml
<indexConfigurations>
    <CustomIndexConfiguration ref="contentSearch/indexConfigurations/defaultSolrIndexConfiguration">
      <fieldMap type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrFieldMap, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider">
        <fieldNames hint="raw:AddFieldByFieldName">
          <field fieldName="text" returnType="string" />
          <field fieldName="webshops" returnType="string" />
          <field fieldName="attributes" returnType="string" />
        </fieldNames>
      </fieldMap>
      <documentOptions type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrDocumentBuilderOptions, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider">
        ...
      </documentOptions>
    </CustomIndexConfiguration>
 </indexConfigurations>
```

My old Lucene config had a fieldMap like this:

```xml
<fieldNames hint="raw:AddFieldByFieldName">
    <field fieldName="text" storageType="YES" indexType="UNTOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f" type="System.String" settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider"/>
    <field fieldName="webshops" storageType="YES" indexType="TOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f" type="System.String" settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider"/>
    <field fieldName="attributes" storageType="YES" indexType="TOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f" type="System.String" settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider">
</fieldNames>
```

I am definitely missing something (otherwise I wouldn't get an error). Buy what?

Using Sitecore 8.1-upd3, Solr 4.10.3, Autofac 4.1, ...

Comment: what version of sitecore and solr are you using?

Comment: Your code looks correct. How do you use that new Index? If you are trying to replace standard Sitecore indexes you need to keep all default fields.

Comment: Could you attach the full stack trace?

Comment: Added version info and full stack trace

Comment: I'm not trying to replace the standard indexes. I have a few extra custom indexes next to the standard Sitecore ones. The application starts, even with some custom indexes, as long as I don't include the ones with a fieldMap in the configuration.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think you may be missing type matches within your field map.
Try adding this section before your `<fieldNames>` section

```xml
<typeMatches hint="raw:AddTypeMatch">
    <typeMatch typeName="string" type="System.String" fieldNameFormat="{0}_s" settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider" />
</typeMatches>
```

I grabbed that from the example `Sitecore.ContentSearch.Solr.DefaultIndexConfiguration.config` file

Alternatively, you can try referencing the default field map like this:

```xml
<fieldMap ref="contentSearch/indexConfigurations/defaultSolrIndexConfiguration/fieldMap">
```

Comment: Your alternative (adding the "ref" to the fieldMap element) did the trick!

Comment: This worked for me as well in working with SOLR for the first time. Elusive error. Thanks Mark!